# How to find same particular word from text file and say it as output?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a text file named, `file.txt` which contains,

```
A: - No such Root Directory
B: - No such Root Directory
C: - Fixed Drive
D: - Fixed Drive
E: - Removable Drive
F: - CD-ROM Drive
G: - Removable Drive
H: - No such Root Directory
I: - No such Root Directory
J: - No such Root Directory
K: - No such Root Directory
M: - No such Root Directory
N: - No such Root Directory
O: - No such Root Directory
P: - No such Root Directory
Q: - No such Root Directory
R: - No such Root Directory
S: - No such Root Directory
T: - No such Root Directory
U: - No such Root Directory
V: - No such Root Directory
W: - No such Root Directory
X: - No such Root Directory
Y: - No such Root Directory
Z: - No such Root Directory
```

In this file, you can notice the word `Removable` present twice in line 5 and line 7.

If it have same particular word `Removable` twice or thrice it need to display output has `Removable word found multiple times`.

If it doesn't have same particular word `Removable` twice or thrice it need to display output has `There is no multiple Removable word found`.

For this output i had running the following program,

```
findstr /b Removable "file.txt" do ( 
echo Removable word found multiple times 
) || ( 
echo There is no multiple Removable word found 
)
pause
```

I know its wrong. But, i tried my best. Please correct me friends. it will be so helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `Find /I /C "Removable"<"file.txt"` to get the number of instances of Removable in that file. Then all you need to do is to check that number. The most common way of doing that is to read that value by placing that command in a for loop.

Like this single line within a Command Prompt window:

```dos
For /F %A In ('Find /I /C "Removable"^<"file.txt"') Do @If %A Lss 1 (Echo=There is no multiple Removable word found) Else Echo Removable word found %A times
```